# What is the meaning of ついクセ in this sentence?

Tags: translation, meaning, adverbs

I cannot find a translation of the word (or phrase) ついクセ in the following sentence.

> 引越してきてからも ついクセで 東京のぶんの天気予報まで見てしまいます

My best guess would be that つい comes from 付く and クセ is 癖 so that the word could mean "acquired bad habit".

Also, I am not entirely sure what the も and the まで are doing in this sentence.

My attempt at a translation would be the following:

> After I moved here, I got into the bad habit of looking at the weather forecast for the region around Tokyo.

Is this somewhat close?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

つい and クセ are two words.

- つい is an adverb, meaning "against one's better judgement" or "unintentional" (although these are very wordy in comparison with the original Japanese)
- クセ is indeed 癖 "(bad) habit" and クセで means "out of habit"

The two adverbs are independent. (You could delete either one, or both, from the sentence and still have a grammatical sentence.)

> 引越してきてからも ついクセで 東京のぶんの天気予報まで見てしまいます
>   After moving here, out of habit I still end up watching even the weather forecast for Tokyo.

- も works like "even" here, since he is watching Tokyo's weather forecast even though he lives somewhere else. It corresponds
- まで is used for emphasis ("up to and including")

The translation still reads like a bumpy ride, but I tried to stick to a literal translation as much as possible.

Comment: What does ぶん do in this sentence?

Comment: @Dav7n 分【ぶん】 means "part". 東京のぶんの天気予報 means the part of the weather forecast that is about Tokyo.